# Finding out if the user manually closed the console window by clicking the red X in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, console

I'm working on a project that calls a console window to process some data based on passed in arguments. What I would like to know is how I can check to see if the user clicked on the red X within the console app. Is there an event I need to handle? Any advice would be greatly appreciated. This is being done using the .NET framework 3.5 using VS2005. Thanks.

Comment: The short answer is 'No.' There is no way to determain how some other process ended its lifetime unless that process provides some means to do so (e.g. its exit code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`SetConsoleCtrlHandler`](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/SetConsoleCtrlHandler.html), [C# example here](http://geekswithblogs.net/mrnat/archive/2004/09/23/11594.aspx).

Comment: This is a great start to what I need. However, how would I be able to modify the return code for this. Example :
private static bool ConsoleCtrlCheck(CtrlTypes ctrlType)
{
    // Put your own handler here
    switch (ctrlType)
    {
         case CtrlTypes.CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT:
         {
           //TODO: Be able to set a custom return code that the program can return.
         }
    }

    return true;
}

Comment: You can set your process exit code by calling `Environment.Exit` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit.aspx